# strange line appears under buttons on hover

Tags: html, css, css-animations

everyone, I have created these buttons that animate when you hover over them. Everything works fine with the animations and how I want it to work functionally but for some reason every time you hover over any of the buttons a strange white line appears underneath. it's faint but it's very noticeable. I just want to know why it's doing this and what I can do to stop it. the code could be viewed [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/wilhelm-coq/pen/BayMgWB)

[image: This is what the lines look like]

The issue started when I added the following bit of css. Is it possible to resolve the problem? Thank you in advance.

```
.hero-content li:hover {    
  transform: translateY(-50px) scale(1) !important; 
  -webkit-filter: blur(0) !important;
  -moz-filter: blur(0) !important;
  -o-filter: blur(0) !important;
  -ms-filter: blur(0) !important;
  filter: blur(0) !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.hero-content:hover li {    
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -o-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
  transform: scale(.97);
  opacity: .9;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue

Comment: The line does not appear in the codepen code. Which browser are you using?

Comment: The line does not appear in chrome or firefox. Please tell me your browser name?

Comment: A line appears for a frame or two on Opera on Linux for me. I wonder if it's actually a render bug - perhaps the blur border gets deleted in the frame after the transform?

Comment: @DumbCoder7 I am using Chrome. Maybe I need to update?

Answer (score 2):

After removing the following CSS properties from [Codepen](https://codepen.io/wilhelm-coq/pen/BayMgWB) the issue was fixed

```
 -webkit-filter: blur(2px);

 filter: blur(2px);
```

Comment: But that also removes the blur effect from the inactive `<li>`...

Comment: Yeah, I was just gonna say what @KenY-N said. I would like to keep the blur effect if possible.